# Convolutionnal neural network for rare event using mel spectrogram

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, audio, conv-neural-network

My purpose was to create a model to detect rare sound in audios
For example,  an audio of 2 hours could contains 2 or 3  of this rare event I can't tell you more about the exact subject so sorry about that (because it's private).

I had to work with several audio file which contained some rare event sound and created my own dataset with it. All audio files are already annotated.

So to achieve this purpose I've done this pipeline:

- cutting all audio file into 10 seconds segments and annotated them
- compute them into a mel-spectrogram
- save them into numpy file
- reload them before the model

Then I standardize every "image"
And use a common architecture of CNN:

```
model = Sequential()
    model.add(Conv2D(128, kernel_size=(5, 5),activation='sigmoid',input_shape=inputShape))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
    model.add(Conv2D(64, (5, 5), activation='sigmoid'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
    model.add(Conv2D(128, (5, 5), activation='sigmoid'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
    model.add(Conv2D(64, (5, 5), activation='sigmoid'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
```

Every step should tell if a segment of 10 second contains the rare event sound or not. So basically it's a binarry classification.

**Problem:** But the model have a very bad recall and accuracy. Nothing that I tried could change this. It's around 60% accuracy and 10% recall on the train data. I will like to improve this.

**What I try:** I already tried transfer learning with vgg16 model, under-sampling cause it was unbalanced and data augmentation. Also I changed the optimiser, decrease or increase the learning rate and use different loss functions

Any ideas will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to me, MFCC features would have been a better approach and using it with a sequence network rather than a convolutional network would have worked much better. For sequences, sequence networks like LSTMs, RNNs, Transformers etc. would work much better.

But, if you still want to go with the above model, you have 5x5 filters which will be less efficient than 2 layers of 3x3 filters. So, reduce these to see what happens with your network. You have then increased and decreased number of filters throughout your network, the number of filters generally follow an increasing sequence as you go deeper. You have used sigmoid activations throughout your network, which is never done. The sigmoid activation should only be on the prediction layer. Rest of them should have ReLU activations. Putting all this together should help your model a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Although your internship would be over and hope you'd be doing better. Working on audio is really a challenging.  Challenges may be as under and you should work/update these and then check accuracy of model.
**1. Size of dataset:** In this case rare sound which occur 2, 3 times in 2 hours audio, would definitely have very less number of samples to train the  model. Although you have done augmentation but after augmentation what is the size of dataset of both classes? plz mention.
**2. Generating Mel-Spec:** Parameters which you used for generating mel-spec are also very important I am giving you sample parameters : n_mels=128, n_fft=512, win_length=400, hop_length=160
**3. Rest** you can follow previous answer.